# Generate sequence in for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This has probably been answered, but I couldn't find the solution to my specific problem:
I am looking for a certain file type (for eg. jpeg) and printing to the user a `message` using the `message()` function. But along with the `message` I want to print a sequence.
The output should read:

```
1. Found filename at System time.
2. Found filename2 at System time.
```

Unfortunately, my output is:

```
1 Found filename at System time
2 Found filename at System time
1 Found filename2 at System time
2 Found filename2 at System time
```

My Code:

```
library(tools)
setwd("/Users/RLearner/Desktop/TEMP")
a<-list.files(getwd(), recursive=TRUE)
for (f in a)
  for (i in 1:length(a))
    if (file_ext(f)=="jpeg")
    {
      message(paste(i, "Found", f, "-", Sys.time(), sep = " "))
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't the following enough?

```
setwd("/Users/RLearner/Desktop/TEMP")
a <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="*jpeg$", recursive=TRUE)

out <- paste(seq_along(a), "Found", "-", a, Sys.time(), sep = " ")
```

**Edit**

I couldn't find a solution by simply feed `message` with `out`. There is still need for a `for` loop. If someone could find a wrapping, please feel free to edit.

```
for (ii in out){
  message(ii)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pascal. But I want to use the `message` function and display to the user. The code works but when I wrap it with `message` it doesn't work :( <br> This little code is going to be part of my very long code which displays messages to user at certain points. I have re-edited my main question and put focus on `message`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time @Pascal. I have posted a solution below. I have done it using the traditional way and using 1 for loop now.

Comment: There is also one loop in my solution.

Comment: I couldn't find a clean solution without the `for` loop. It is annoying me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! If i declare a variable `i<-0` and then increment it in the `if` statement, it works: My code:

```
library(tools)
setwd("/Users/RLearner/Desktop/TEMP")
a<-list.files(getwd(), recursive=TRUE)
i<-0
for (f in a)
if (file_ext(f)=="jpeg")
{
message(paste(i+1, "Found", f, "-", Sys.time(), sep = " "))
i<-i+1
}
```